# Cortando strings da direita para esquerda

Tags: php, string

Tenho uma coluna no banco de dados com o nome de `codigo`, na qual a formatação é assim:

```
18000001
```

Onde o **18** significa o ano que estamos e o **1** é o código de cada resultado. Sabendo que esse código pode ser maior que **1** digito **18000011** e assim sucessivamente, preciso retirar somente o valor final antes de chegar ao zero, exemplo:

```
1800044 - Preciso pegar só o 44

1800444 - Preciso pegar o 444

1804444 - Preciso pegar o 4444
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```
$codigo = "1804444";
echo intval(substr($codigo, -5));
```

A função substr remove o 18 da string e depois esta string é convertida para inteiro retornando no caso do exemplo acima 4444.

Comment: @NicholasRuschelKrüger se já testou o código? porque a lógica do amigo da resposta está certa!

Comment: @NicholasRuschelKrüger utilizei a função intval justamente para isso, como ele faz a conversão para inteiro os zeros são ignorados.

Comment: sim, perdoe-me não tinha testado o código ants de comentar bobagem, muito obrigado amigo!

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer desta maneira

```
$codigo = "";
$cod = 4444;
if($cod != ""){
    $anoAgora = substr(date("Y"),2,2);
    $ano =  substr($cod,0,2);
    $num =  substr($cod,2,5);
    $numInt = intval($num);
    if($anoAgora != $ano){
        $codigo = $anoAgora . "00001";
    }else{
        $numInt += 1;
        $strZeros ='';
        //obter o número de digitos que tem a variável 
        $num1 = strlen($numInt);
        //obter número de digitos(zeros) que faltam adicionar
        $num3 = ((5 - $num1));
        //criar a sequência de zeros em falta
        for($i=0;$i<$num3;$i++){
            $strZeros .='0';
        }
        $seqNum = $strZeros;
        $codigo = $ano . $seqNum . $numInt;
    }   
}else{
    $anoAgora = date("Y");
    $codigo = substr($anoAgora,2,2) . "00001";
}
```